# how to connect omap to oled display

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, lcd

as you guys see the title , I would like to connect Micro OLED display to dart4460(omap4460).

I am not sure but I guess I can use parallel LCD port in dart4460 to connect OLED display.

here are what I want to connect displays.

1) http://1103zzeykfq2w1en1xnkh94yk.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/SXGA-Datasheet-w-DF12-rev-13.pdf

2) http://www.olightek.com/products_detail/&productId=32.html : below of that page has a datasheet for device

actually I am beginner for this process

what i really want to do is to connect micro display to dart4460 and to show screen of linux or android

so I am studying for writing framebuffer driver.

anyways my questions are :

(1) I want to know which ports or pin I should use when I write framebuffer driver and how I can connect ports.

(2) if I can't connect between board and display , which one do I need? what should I do to make it possible?

(3) I would like to know how write framebuffer driver by seeing OLED datasheet. could you guys recommend the site OR books to study????

(4) I studied fbtft in raspberry pi site(github.com/notro). can I apply those sources for dart4460 for micro oled ????

Thanks you in advance ! 
If you help me , I will really really appreciate that !

Comment: Sounds like a hardware question.  Not a question for SO.

Comment: It seems a hardware question, but there is also a requirement for a driver software writing mechanism that will help the question being answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLED is no different than LCD from the driver's perspective, so I'd recommend to start looking at TI provided Linux LCD drivers[1] (*linux_src/drivers/video/fbdev/omap* or *omap2*). Your MCU has DSS[2], so you don't need to do "pin level" drivers, only connect correct pins and configure registers. There's a big chance that your LCD will be supported out of a box with only timing modifications and correct kernel config. Just look for ready boards that use the same MCU and see how they implement it; Pandaboard[3] comes to mind first. Sadly, I don't know any resources on this topics besides random scrap of information all around the net. I've ported few LCDs to other ARM MCUs, but it was by trial and error, not a methodical approach.

P.S. If you want to use advanced features (sensors, parameter modification etc.) of your LCD, you can do that separately on userspace or as a kernel module.

1. http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Sitara_SDK_Linux_LCDC
2. http://www.variscite.com/images/DART-4460-DS_107.pdf
3. http://pandaboard.org/

Comment: Thanks . you are very kind . I know what to do from now